# Stacked Bar Plot with barplot() from CSV

Tags: r, histogram, bar-chart, opencsv

I am trying to obtain a `barplot` from a CSV file but I having some problems.

```
P;I;R;F1;F2;F3
20140101;50;20;7;7;16
20140108;55;22;9;9;15
20140115;52;21,4;8,6;10;12
```

First I open my .csv

```
d<-read.csv('d:\\Users\\140050es\\Desktop\\R\\test2.csv', header = F, sep = ",")
```

Then I assign a table: ( I don't know if this step is ok)

```
data<-table(d$I,d$R,d$F1,d$F2,d$F3)
```

And then I plot my data:

```
barplot(data,main="barplot()",xlab="Periodo",col=c("blue","red","green","orange","gold")
```

But R doesn't plot anything.

Comment: I think one probles is that R reads wrong the csv. file.

Comment: One error is in the sep="" field

Comment: Try using `read.csv2` instead or defining `sep = ";"`. Your data is separated by ";" not ",". That is the default in `read.csv2` so you wouldn't need to specify the `sep` argument in that case.

Comment: ok! Thats correct! but is ok the way I asign the "data" table for plotting after?

Comment: I doubt that that is necessary. When reading your data from a `csv` file, you have it in `d` which is a `data.frame` and you can use that as input for plotting a barplot. `table()` is a function that creates a table of frequencies, see `?table` - It's not clear to me what exactly you want to plot. Can you describe the desired barplot based on the sample data that you show in your question?

Comment: # Stacked Bar Plot with Colors and Legend
counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",
  xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),
  legend = rownames(counts))

Comment: try to compile this and you will see exactly what do I want! thanks

Comment: That is an example of a stacked barplot, but what I meant is which exact variables (columns) do you want to plot in your stacked bar plot? In your sample data there are the variables P (which is a date), I, R, F1, F2, F3 -> what should be the x-axis (equivalent to Number of Gears) and what is the stacking variable (equivalent to 0/1)?

Comment: Exactly!! The equivalent to "Number of Gears" is my variable P and the stacking variable are I,R,F1,F2,F3. 

I wanted to reprent for example row 1:
in 50 (I) there are 20 (R) + 7(F1) 7 (F2) and 16 (F3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `barplot` each *column* of the input matrix corresponds to a group of bars, and each *row* to different bars within groups. Because it seems like your groups are defined by the 'P' variable, you need to transpose the data. Then each *column* corresponds to one 'P date', and rows correspond to values for respectively I, R, F1, F2 and F3.

The '**Value**' of the `barplot` call is "A numeric vector [...] giving the coordinates of all the bar midpoints drawn, useful for adding to the graph.". Thus, we collect these midpoints in a variable 'bp', and use them as positions (`at` argument) for the x `axis` labels.

```
df <- read.csv2(text = "P;I;R;F1;F2;F3
                20140101;50;20;7;7;16
                20140108;55;22;9;9;15
                20140115;52;21,4;8,6;10;12")

bp <- barplot(t(df[ , -1]), col = c("blue", "red", "green", "orange", "gold"))

axis(side = 1, at = bp, labels = df$P)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly!! The equivalent to "Number of Gears" is my variable P and the stacking variable are I,R,F1,F2,F3. I wanted to reprent for example row 1: in 50 (I) there are 20 (R) + 7(F1) 7 (F2) and 16 (F3)

Comment: you are representing the sum os my stacking variables.
Maybe this barplot() i want isn't named Stacked Bar Plot .......

Comment: To me it is unclear what you wish to achieve with `table(d$V1,d$V2,d$F1,d$F2,d$F3)`. The variable names does not correspond to your data. Please also read carefully about the `height` argument in `?barplot`, and play with the examples. And yes, the plot in my answer is a stacked barplot.

Comment: What should I do if I don't want to consider my variable P (because its the sum and its indifrent to have it on the bar plot)???

Comment: And I really don't understand what you mean by "don't want to consider my variable P". Which variable should be on the x-axis?

Comment: Sorry Henrik I meant my variable I

Comment: without changing my .csv how can i do to 'ignore' I column

Comment: Your trip on the R path will be so much smoother if you read some basic introductory texts (see e.g. [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)), and read carefully about subsetting data. See e.g. `?Extract`, [**here**](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/tutorials/impatient-r/more-r-subscript/) and [**here**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html). Then try `df[ , -c(1:2)]`.